# What is exactly the edition/version of my Vitz 2010?

Tags: toyota, vitz

I have seen on internet different versions of Vitz 2010 model like F1 and others. I am not clear exactly what is my version?

Update

On the data plate, I found model mentioned as

dba-ksp90-ahxdk-b

I am not sure whether it is F1 or any other version

Comment: Look for a manufacturer's plate inside the driver's side door jamb; it may be on the bottom, or it may be on the body pillar at the rear of the door.

Comment: Can you please convert your comment into answer with a sample photo please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the car's serial number, a dealer (and, perhaps some websites) can determine the model, year, and trim of the vehicle as it was manufactured.

The car's serial number can be found on the manufacturer's data plate. Here in the US, they're almost always on the door jamb on the driver's side of the car. Here are some examples (photos by the author):

In this picture from a 2019 VW Jetta, the plate is located on the door jamb, at the bottom rear corner:

[image]

In this picture from a 2014 BMW i3, the plate is located on the front door jamb, above the center:

[image]

In this picture from a 2011 BMW x3, the plate is located on the rear jamb:

[image]

In other markets, the plates or labels may be in other locations.
Speak to a Toyota dealer (or knowledgeable private mechanic) to find out more about your vehicle.

Comment: If possible, can you please check and answer my updated question

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea what this Toyota number (or any Toyota number) means. You should be able to find out via an internet search, or a Toyota dealer, or a knowledgeable private mechanic.

Comment: Its ok, no worries. Thanks for you time and detailed advice that you shared in your answer already